# Would it be best for PowerShell scripts to also have a shebang?

Tags: shebang, powershell

Shell scripts are better when having a *[shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))* like so:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "The shebang above this line works like a typical a comment but with a purpose"
```

PowerShell scripts are also shell scripts. So it should be okay to do like so:

```bsh
#!/usr/local/bin/pwsh
echo "The shebang above this line works like a typical a comment but with a purpose"
```

It seems to does not make sense if the script was intended for Windows machines but for Linux and Mac machines they seem to make sense.

Do you think it would be best for PowerShell scripts to also have a shebang?

Comment: AFAIR, `pwsh` prior to version 6.0 did not support the concept of shebang.

Comment: @fpmurphy the first version of `pwsh` is 6.0. It's also the first version to run on non-Windows platforms. Older version are `powershell` and runs on Windows only which has no idea of shebang

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell scripts are primarily run under Windows and this OS pays attention to the file extension of all files except for `.exe`, `.com`, `.cmd`, `.bat` which are executed directly. Windows also doesn't have the concept of executable files - the so called "executable" bit in Unix OSes.

Linux on the other hand uses the shebang for files marked as executable to find out which interpreter to use, so the shebang becomes crucial.

> Do you think it would be best for PowerShell scripts to also have a shebang?

For Windows machines it makes zero sense, for Linux machines it perfectly makes sense. In the end it's up to you to decide. Adding the PS shebang won't hurt, so you might add it to all your scripts, only I didn't know people use PS under Linux.

Comment: Does that mean that you do not recommend having a shebang? Only for windows machines? or even for unix and linux machines?

Comment: For Windows machines it makes zero sense, for Linux machines it perfectly makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

When you run an executable script on UNIX/Linux derived systems, the kernel (or sometimes the shell) looks at the first line for a `#!` (shebang) marker that indicates the name of the interpreter to use.

If you don't have a shebang then there is no clear information about the method by which the script should be executed, and it's up to the user to specify an interpreter explcitly.

For example,

```
bash somescript         # user calls bash explicitly to run the script
```

vs

```
chmod a+x somescript    # make executable
head -n1 somescript     # show the first line
#!/bin/bash

./somescript            # the script itself defines bash to execute it
```

The same can apply for any interpreter, not just a standard shell. So you can have `#!/bin/awk`, `#!/usr/bin/perl`, etc.

Similarly there is no reason why you shouldn't have `#!/usr/local/bin/pwsh` provided that the interpreter can execute code read from *stdin*. It's what I'd aim to do.

Comment: Does that mean that you recommend still having a shebang? and only do so for unix and linux machines?

Comment: I would recommend a `#!` shebang for any script on a UNIX/Linux machine that could benefit from it. Also, note that although the concept isn't implemented for Windows powershell, there's nothing stopping you using it there, because the `#` character introduces a comment line

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you want your shebang to start with `#!/usr/bin/env` because the location of env is always in `/usr/bin/` on all x-nixes. Unlike `env`, `bash` can sometimes be in `/usr/bin`, or `/bin` or both (depending on the OS). `/usr/bin/env` will search your path to find the right executable and makes your script far more portable.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env pwsh
```

Would find `pwsh` on your path, provided that you are not root, as root often does not include `/usr/local/bin` on the path

The exception to this is when you are dealing with programs that have multiple environments (like a python virtualenv), where the shebang is used to call a specific environment of python. But virutalenvs are never portable, so sacrificing portability here is consistent.

Comment: There are definitely pros and cons with using `#!/usr/bin/env`. In many cases I want my script to run regardless of the user's PATH. Your version requires it to be correct. It seems YMMV rather than a hard and fast rule